# Repositioning cursor in contenteditable

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, caret

I am strugling with repositioning the cursor in my contenteditable.

I'm trying to highlight the user input while typing after the input of a "#". For this I retrieve the cursor position upon last input and replace the input between cursor and "#" with the highlighted text. As expected the cursor gets reset to the beginning of the input-field and I need to reset the cursor to the prev. retrieved position on each input. That's where the problem is:

My current version puts the cursor in front of the "#" and consequently one step back on each input, meaning it appears stationary during input. Incrementing the retireved position, or the position within the set-function has no effect on the actual position, which I do not understand at all.

```
function setCaret(element, caretPosition) {
  const range = document.createRange();
  const selection = window.getSelection();

  // Check if the element has child nodes
  if (element.childNodes.length > 0) {
    const textNode = element.childNodes[0];
    const textLength = textNode.textContent.length;
    const normalizedPosition = Math.min(caretPosition, textLength);

    // Check if the normalized position is within the valid range
    if (normalizedPosition >= 0 && normalizedPosition <= textLength) {
      range.setStart(textNode, normalizedPosition);
      range.collapse(true);
      selection.removeAllRanges();
      selection.addRange(range);
    }
  }

  element.focus();
}


textInput.addEventListener('input', (event) => {
  const text = textInput.innerText;
  if (event.data === '#') {
    tagInputActive = true;
    hashtagPosition = text.lastIndexOf('#');
  }

  if (tagInputActive) {
    const updatedText = textInput.innerText;
    const caretPosition = getCaretIndex(textInput);
    tagInput = updatedText.substring(hashtagPosition, caretPosition)
    console.log(caretPosition);
    console.log(tagInput);

    const highlightInput = `<span class="highlight">${tagInput}</span>`;
    const text = textInput.innerText;
    const newUpdate = text.substring(0, hashtagPosition) + highlightInput + text.substring(hashtagPosition + tagInput.length);
    textInput.innerHTML = newUpdate;
    setCaret(textInput, caretPosition);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this code to set the range, considering more parameters and it worked for my example as well. Didn't get around yet to see why exactly this works and what I did doesnt, but for anyone struggling with the same issue, here is the link:

https://jsfiddle.net/nrx9yvw9/5/

```
function createRange(node, chars, range) {
  if (!range) {
    range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(node);
    range.setStart(node, 0);
  }

  if (chars.count === 0) {
    range.setEnd(node, chars.count);
  } else if (node && chars.count > 0) {
    if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
      if (node.textContent.length < chars.count) {
        chars.count -= node.textContent.length;
      } else {
        range.setEnd(node, chars.count);
        chars.count = 0;
      }
    } else {
      for (let lp = 0; lp < node.childNodes.length; lp++) {
        range = createRange(node.childNodes[lp], chars, range);

        if (chars.count === 0) {
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return range;
}

function setCurrentCursorPosition(element, chars) {
  if (chars >= 0) {
    const selection = window.getSelection();
    let range = createRange(element, { count: chars });

    if (range) {
      range.collapse(false);
      selection.removeAllRanges();
      selection.addRange(range);
    }
  }
}
```